# fire external script background with js?

Tags: javascript, php, content-management-system

is it possible to fire the execution of a script in the background via click?
I am within a CMS/CRM and want to trigger an external file to load when clicking on a certain link within the CMS/CRM.

e.g. activate the php.mailer to send an email.

It seems to be a security issue when using (cross domain vulnerability?)

```
foobar.onload()
```

and if it weren't, it would not execute the file in the background.
I have seen that it was solved in python using with

```
subprocessor()
```

.

The external script would be on my domain though and not touch the CMS / CRM.
Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look on Access-Control-Allow-Origin header 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you can't access to the filesystem, but you can use ajax to request some url with differents methods (GET, POST...).

The script you called from the url can execute a function to send an email if you want.

If you know jQuery, you can do something like that in JavaScript

```
$.get("myScript.php");
```

And in your **myScript.php** file :

```php
mail('you@mailhost.com', 'Hello', 'Cool !');
```

And if your php script is not on the same domain, you should check **Access-Control-Allow-Origin header** that allow your client (the browser which execute the ajax script) to call the remote php script

Comment: Thanks! While I could not apply this solution within the current CRM. Your answer helped me with another :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have your click event handler make an AJAX request. For example:

```
myButton.onclick = function (e)
{
    // Make an AJAX request with jQuery
    $.get('/ajax/getFoo.php', function (data)
    {
        // This runs when the AJAX call returns
    });
}
```

Alternatively, you might look at the jQuery .load() function too:

http://api.jquery.com/load/